# Show that $y^2-3xy+2x^2=1$ is a solution of the differential equation $4x-36+y'(2y-3x)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to show that the given equation($1.$)  is a solution of the differential equation($2.$)

1. $y^2-3xy+2x^2=1$
2. $4x-3y+y'(2y-3x)=0$

I need to put the derivative of $1.$ in $2.$?
thanks.

Comment: why don't you find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and plug it into the LHS of 2 and see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The first equation actually gives a curve $F(x,y)=y^2-3xy+2x^2-1=0$. And the second gives the equation containing the derivative of $y$ w.r.t $x$. So you could try [implicit function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) to find $y'=-\frac{\partial F/\partial x}{\partial F/\partial y}$ from (1). You will see that would be equivalent to (2).

---

And you may mistake 36 for 3y.

Comment: @OfirAttia How did you get that? Partial derivative of a polynomial is still a polynomial. Where does fraction come from?

Comment: derivatives are: $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=4x-3y$$ and $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=2y-3x$$ what now?

Comment: Got it. thanks.

Comment: @OfirAttia That's right. :)

Comment: btw, $$y'=\frac{3y-4x}{2y-3x}$$ or I missed some minus or its not equal ( look on the partial )

Comment: @OfirAttia Everything looks good to me.

Answer (score 3):

A general Hint for the **inverse problem**:

Assume you have $$y'=f\left(\frac{ax+by+c}{Ax+By+C}\right),~~aB-bA\neq 0$$ then by setting $x=u+h,~~y=v+k$ where in $P(h,k)$ is the point of intersection of lines above, you can reduced the original OE to a homogenous simple OE.

Comment: Very nice hint my friend! +1

Comment: @Amzoti: Thanks my friend. Best wishes for you. :)